# How to save a text information with the formatting italic, bold, underline in visual basic 6

Tags: vb6

How to save a text information with the formatting italic, bold, underline, small, medium, large?
I have a menu, from where I can Save the text as a file, Open a file in my text editor, Exit from my program, but I don't know the coding for Saving and Opening a file, with the format bold, italic, underline, small, medium, large of a text.
Please any suggestions, I need to save the file as fmt extention, i guess i need a separate sequential file, but I just don't know how...
Please help me for this matter.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: answer is updated, check that out :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't simply save a text file with **BOLD**, *Italic*, you need Rich Text Format In your App, place RTFTextEditor and place some code in a button to save all those text whatever in RTF t a text file with your desired extension

For instance:

```
 RichTextBox.savefile("C:\Sample.txt")
```

Comment: How does it smell now, Barbecue?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to RTF is to use the DHTMLEdit control to load, edit, save HTML.  But few know how to use it and the SDK doesn't seem to be available any longer.

I'm not sure what the use of non-standard file extensions buys you either.